# Combining an INSERT INTO w/ a VALUE and a SELECT + INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, sql-insert, insert-into

So basically I need to combine this:

```
INSERT INTO order(B_DATUM, orderNR, L_DATUM)
VALUES ('1999-04-23', '0205', DATE_ADD('1999-04-23', INTERVAL 7 DAY))
```

with these:

```
INSERT INTO bestel( BEDRAG ) 
SELECT 0.92*SUM( bestreg.aantal * bestreg.best_pr ) 
FROM bestreg
INNER JOIN bestel ON bestreg.bestelnr = bestel.bestelnr
WHERE bestel.bestelnr = '0205'
```

&

```
INSERT INTO order( lev_code ) 
SELECT offertes.lev_code FROM order
INNER JOIN (orderreg INNER JOIN offertes 
ON orderreg.art_lev = offertes.art_lev)  
ON orderreg.bestelnr = order.ordernr
WHERE order.ordernr = '0205'
```

I've read in previous questions that you have to place the VALUES inside the SELECT but once I get to the INNER JOIN it keeps messing up.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the difference between first two queries?

Comment: I think you mean you want something like this: `INSERT INTO my_table (SELECT x,y,z, '1994-01-01' + INTERVAL 7 DAY FROM somewhere)`

Comment: @Lali - Good point, copy pasted to fast and left a (crucial) part out.. thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

ANSI SQL solution, not sure if MySQL supports it:

```
INSERT INTO order(B_DATUM, orderNR, L_DATUM)
VALUES ('1999-04-23', '0205', DATE_ADD('1999-04-23', INTERVAL 7 DAY))
union all
VALUES ('1999-04-23', '0205', DATE_ADD('1999-04-23', INTERVAL 7 DAY))
union all
SELECT offertes.lev_code FROM order
INNER JOIN (orderreg INNER JOIN offertes 
ON orderreg.art_lev = offertes.art_lev)  
ON orderreg.bestelnr = order.ordernr
WHERE order.ordernr = '0205'
```

BTW, `ORDER` is a reserved word in ANSI SQL, you may need to delmit it, like `"order"` or perhaps with back-ticks.

Comment: I think this query will not run, beacuse join syntax is not correct.

Comment: The syntax is ANSI SQL correct. I don't know MySQL, but how do want to correct it?

Comment: Well i dont know this, that this is also a correct syntax. Thanks for updating me.

Comment: Tried running it in mysql but got a syntax error, I'm to much of a novice to know why that could be but thanks for the effort !

Comment: Yes all original parts worked seperately. Posted the working combination now. Again, not ANSI SQL but MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply Try this:-

```
 INSERT INTO order(B_DATUM, orderNR, L_DATUM, lev_code)
 SELECT ('1999-04-23', '0205', DATE_ADD('1999-04-23', INTERVAL 7 DAY), SELECT offertes.lev_code FROM order
                                                                       INNER JOIN orderreg ON orderreg.bestelnr = order.ordernr 
                                                                       INNER JOIN offertes ON orderreg.art_lev = offertes.art_lev  
                                                                       WHERE order.ordernr = '0205')
```

Comment: Hi, using a VALUE + SELECT gives a syntax error in mysql (at least in phpmyadmin it does). Thanks tho !

Answer (score 0):

So I kept trying and got this to work eventually (MYSQL):

```
        INSERT INTO order(B_DATUM, orderNR, L_DATUM , bedrag, lev_code)
        SELECT '1999-04-23', '0205', 
        DATE_ADD('1999-04-23', INTERVAL 7 DAY),
        0.92*SUM( bestreg.aantal * bestreg.best_pr ), offertes.lev_code 
        FROM order INNER JOIN (bestreg INNER JOIN offertes 
        ON bestreg.art_lev = offertes.art_lev)  ON bestreg.ordernr = order.ordernr
        WHERE order.ordernr = '0205'
```

Previous answers to similar questions were right stating you use the VALUES in the SELECT and just discard the 'VALUES' statement.

Thanks for comments & replies!